# How to retrieve values of an enumeration of given string literal

Tags: c#, excel

Need to get a value of an enumeration of a given string literal like "xlCenter" (these values are cut and pasted from Excel Macro).
I would like to retrieve the actual constant value (int) -4108="xLCenter" via com marshaling is this possible ? if so how ?

Ideally I am looking for function like this

```
public int ExcelConstant(string constantName)
{ ...}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio you should add a reference to Excel in your project. You will find Excel in the **COM** tab of the **Add Reference** dialog. The name is **Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library** (or a slightly different name if you are using another version of Excel).

In your project you are then able to use types in the `Microsoft.Office` namespaces. For instance you would probably want to use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Constants.xlCenter` enumeration constant. If you need the numerical value you simply cast it to an integer:

```
Int32 xlCenterValue = (Int32) Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Constants.xlCenter;
```

Or you could create a function as you have outlined in your question:

```
public Int32 ExcelConstant(String constantName) {
  return Enum.Parse(
    typeof(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Constants),
    constantName
  );
}
```

If you want to call the Excel automation API from managed code you probably don't care about the numerical values of the enumerations. Instead you should use the enumeration directly in your code:

```
var worksheet = (Worksheet) excel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
var cell = (Range) worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Constants.xlCenter;
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the exact answer you want but I suggest taking a look at `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Constants`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.constants%28office.11%29.aspx